# caffe installation : opencv libpng16.so.16 linkage issues

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, anaconda, caffe

I am trying to compile caffe with python interface on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

I have installed Anaconda and opencv with `conda install opencv`. I have also installed all the requirement stipulated in the coffee and changed the commentary blocks in `makefile.config` so that PYTHON_LIB and PYTHON_INCLUDE point towards Anaconda distributions.

When I am calling `make all`, the following command is issued:

```
g++ .build_release/tools/caffe.o -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin -pthread 
-fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DWITH_PYTHON_LAYER 
-I/home/andrei/anaconda/include 
-I/home/andrei/anaconda/include/python2.7 
-I/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
-I/usr/local/include 
-I/home/andrei/anaconda/lib 
-I/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-I/lib64 
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-I.build_release/src 
-I./src 
-I./include 
-I/usr/include 
-Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe 
-L/home/andrei/anaconda/lib 
-L/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/././ 
-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib 
-L/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/././libpng16.so.16 
-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-L/lib64 
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-L/usr/lib 
-L.build_release/lib  
-lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy 
-llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lm 
-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ 
-lboost_python -lpython2.7 -lcblas -latlas \
-Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
```

However, it is stopped by the following set of errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpng16.so.16, needed by /home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_bgr@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_filter@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_rgb_to_gray@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_init_io@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_swap@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_palette_to_rgb@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_strategy@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_get_tRNS@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_write_info@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_packing@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_end@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_update_info@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_write_image@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_write_end@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_image@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_info@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_alpha@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_error@PNG16_0'
/home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16@PNG16_0'
```

Following the advice from this question: [Caffe install on ubuntu for anaconda with python 2.7 fails with libpng16.so.16 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962975/caffe-install-on-ubuntu-for-anaconda-with-python-2-7-fails-with-libpng16-so-16-n), I tired running the `ldd /home/andrei/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui`, and obtained the following output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1a104000)
    libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /home/andrei/anaconda/lib/././libopencv_core.so.2.4 (0x00007ff18e8a0000)
    libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 => /home/andrei/anaconda/lib/././libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 (0x00007ff18e3f0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff18e1ec000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff18dfce000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff18ddc6000)
    libz.so.1 => /home/andrei/anaconda/lib/././libz.so.1 (0x00007ff18dbb0000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /home/andrei/anaconda/lib/././libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007ff18d979000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /home/andrei/anaconda/lib/././libpng16.so.16 (0x00007ff18d737000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff18d535000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff18d22d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff18cf29000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff18cc23000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff18ca0d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff18c648000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff18f0d0000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ff18c40a000)
```

I then proceeded to add all the required directories into the `INCLUDE_DIRS` and `LIBRARY_DIRS` of the `make.config` file (hence additional `-I` and `-L` in the `g++` call above), including the explicit link to `libpng16.so.16` already present in anaconda libraries. This have however not resolved the issue. I also tried adding the file to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$LD_RUN_PATH`, but without any effect.

What might the problem be and how could I resolve it?

Comment: Can you paste your make.config somewhere on pastebin of anywhere else?

Comment: sure: https://gist.github.com/chiffa/0c3f8b69e250eb5d108f

Comment: The differencies between your and my makefile.config: I use BLAS:=open In python_include I also have $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib. Try to change the stuff? I was able to built with my makefile: http://pastebin.ru/MNM2N0FC

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I came across the same problem. I found it similar to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2007, and I solved it by

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s ~/anaconda/lib/libpng16.so.16 libpng16.so.16
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: @yangjie: Could you explain a bit more what is happening here?

Answer (score 4):

It works with me based on the solution here https://github.com/hashdist/hashstack/issues/670

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/anaconda2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This shall be added in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: shoud be export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/anaconda2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

There is no space between the =

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you've added `/home/andrei/anaconda/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable, so that `libpng-config` resolves to `/home/andrei/anaconda/bin/libpng16-config`, which is what is causing `cmake` to try and link with libpng v1.6.

Strip the `anaconda` dir from your `PATH` environment variable and `libpng-config` should default to libpng v1.2 in `/usr/lib` or similar.

Comment: Nope, apparently the problem is elsewhere. Removing Anaconda from the PATH didn't really work. Beyond that, I am trying to compile caffe explicitely against anaconda version of Python and openCV, so it is normal that it wants to use libpng16.so.16, which is already included in the Anaconda PATH.